# Getting images from SQLite database and displaying them into GridView Android Studio

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, gridview

I am new to Android Studio and I have been having some trouble with getting images, which have been stored into a database, and then displaying them into a GridView. Is there a way I can get the number of images stored in the database and then displaying them one by one, each in a different cell within GridView? This is my code so far:

**NewsAddImageActivity class**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class NewsAddImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //public MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    String imgDecodableString;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    int tabNo;
    Tab1Class t1;
    Tab2Class t2;
    Tab3Class t3;
    Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_newsaddimage);

        final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadImagefromGallery(v);
            }
        });

        Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                dbHelper.addEntry(dbHelper.getBytes(bitmap)); //add image to database


                byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(1); //get image from database as byte 

                dbHelper.getImage(image); //converts byte to bitmap

                if(tabNo==0){
                  //place image in the grid view of tab1
                }else if(tabNo==1) {
                  //place image in the grid view of tab2
                }else if(tabNo==2){
                  //place image in the grid view of tab3
                }

                finish();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    private byte[] imageButtonToByte(ImageButton image){
        Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray=stream.toByteArray();
        return byteArray;
    }


    public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
        // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();


                ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
                bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageButton.getDrawable()).getBitmap();



                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                imageButton.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }

    public void getTab(int num){
        switch(num) {
            case 0: tabNo=0;
            case 1: tabNo=1;
            case 2: tabNo=2;
        }
    }

}
```

**MyDatabaseHelper Class**

```
package com.example.mobilecomputingapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;



public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ImagesDB";

    // Table Names
    private static final String DB_TABLE = "imageTable";

    // column names
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "image_name";
    private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image_data";

    // Table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_IMAGE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + "("+
            KEY_NAME + " TEXT," +
            KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB);";

    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // creating table
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE);

        // create new table
        onCreate(db);
    }

   /* public void addEntry( String name, byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME,    name);
        cv.put(KEY_IMAGE,   image);
        database.insert( DB_TABLE, null, cv );
    }*/

    public void addEntry( byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_IMAGE,   image);
        database.insert( DB_TABLE, null, cv );
    }
    // convert from bitmap to byte array
    public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

    // convert from byte array to bitmap
    public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Storing BLOBs in a database is a **worst practice**. Store the **paths**, instead.

Comment: How can this be done? @Rotwang

Comment: paths are just plain strings. i.e.: "/mnt/sdcard0/somefolder/yourimage.jpg"

Comment: The thing is that the images are not being stored on disk, but in a database.@Rotwang

Comment: I already told you: **worst practice**.

Comment: However, how can you get a path to an image which is being stored in a database? @Rotwang

Comment: Store the images on storage (involontary word joke). Save and retrieve their paths. The app will be not only faster, but your db would keep lighter (and intrinsically faster as well). Mind that SQLite databases are very limited in size.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a bitmap of images which you want to select to save in db < don't save images save the URI(Path) of image like this.In this code selectedd images is an array which holds the selected images .And you should make method of insert images in Dbhelper and pass the string like this ..

```
Bitmap bitmap = thumbnails[i];
                       Uri uri = Utility.getImageUri(getContext(),bitmap);
                        byte[] path = Utility.getBytes(bitmap);
                        cnt++;
                        selecteddimages.add(uri);
                        String s = uri.toString();
                        databaseHelper.insertContact(s);




DBHELPER method of insert


   public void insertContact (String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", name);
         long result=db.insert("images", null, contentValues);
        if (result==-1){
            Toast.makeText(context,"not save",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
                Toast.makeText(context,"save",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


UTILITIES CLass for getimage URI
   public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

 public static Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```